# Построение фрактала

Tags: c#, алгоритм, java, фракталы

Кто работал с фракталами, обьясните, как в L-системе происходит поворот на угол, например:

```
переменные : F
константы  : + −
начало  : F
правила  : −F++F−
угол  : 45°
```

Есть две точки (начальное положение кривой Леви), например, (-10;0) и (10; 0), тоесть прямая. Какие точки следущие (вторая итерация), тоесть как происходит поворт? Какую точку брать за точку опоры ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для правила `F -> -F++F-` нужно взять исходный отрезок, далее из первой точки отрезка под -45 градусов провести отрезок, затем из конца проведенного отрезка повернуть на 90 (два раза по 45) градусов, провести еще один отрезок. Причем после такого рисования должны попасть в конец исходного отрезка - исходя из этого выбирается масштаб новых отрезков относительно исходного.

Для данного правила длина новых отрезков будет `|AB|*sqrt(1/2)`, т.е. в данном случае мы, имея гипотенузу равнобедренного прямоугольного треугольника, заменяем ее на два катета.

В русской википедии есть рекурсивный алгоритм на php для кривой Леви (и некоторых других тоже).

Можно обойтись впрочем из без рекурсии, а прогнать правила в цикле, начиная с F, получить длинную строчку из F, плюсов и минусов, просчитать размер отрезка для полученного поколения и отстроить по этой строке в соответствии с имеющимися правилами кривую по порядку следования F, плюсов и минусов.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то должно быть вот так? Тоесть, поворот происходит относительно текущей точки? http://s12.postimg.org/jhb39aob1/fractal_builing.jpg

Comment: Да, все верно. Рисование (черепаший метод) идет из одной точки. Начинаем из первой точки и выполняя повороты, рисуя отрезки, мы двигаемся по кривой.